# How to bring up relocation during a job interview?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, relocation

I'm currently living and working on a work visa in country X.
I need to move countries for family reasons, so now I'm in a process of looking for a new job in country Y. I'm not a citizen of X or Y.

Obviously, I'm only looking for positions that offer relocation to Y (not necessary relocation assistance, just the ability to work in another country), but I'm not sure how to inform my potential employer that I NEED to relocate. Most of the jobs I'm looking at offer locations in several countries including Y and remote work, but I need to be working from country Y to get a visa. Even if my hypothetical new employer does not provide financial assistance, employing a foreigner according to the labor laws of country Y is more difficult than hiring a local, so I want to bring up the topic as correctly as possible.

Is it appropriate to mention personal reasons, or the fact that if I accept the offer I will not be able to stay in my current country, or is it better to be as general as possible?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the question. Most jobs offers are for a very specific location. It should be clear that you will relocate if you apply for a job in a different country.

Comment: Most of jobs that I'm looking at also offer remote jobs, which would be less costly for the company than relocating someone. However, I cannot work remotely.

Comment: Sorry, this is really confusing. So you currently work in country X and now you want to work and live in country Y. Is that correct? So you are looking for local jobs in Y and can't find any? Is that the problem ?

Comment: @Hilmar I live in country X and now you want to work and live in country Y. I need the potential employer to know that I cannot stay in X and work remotely and they would need to go through the process of employing a foreigner in country Y.

Comment: Why not simply apply for jobs at Y? Skips the entire confusion.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Possibly because X is a wealthy first world country and Y is not.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I do not speak Y well enough.

Comment: Updated the questions based on the comment. I hope it is more clear now. Honestly, I was not expecting this question to be this confusing. I guess this is an uncommon situation.

Comment: So you and your family need to relocate to country Y, but you don't speak the language of country Y? And you need to work for an employer that will let you live and work in country Y, even if that employer is not headquartered in country Y?

Comment: @shoover I'm honestly not sure why it matters if the headquarters of the employer is in Y or not if it is a viable location for them. Could you explain?

Comment: @sleeper based on the update this is actually quite unique, as they would need legal presence in country Y to hire you. This is getting very tangled up, and honestly I think the only way for you will be to either start some sort of solo-business (whatever Y allows, you'll need an accountant), or look for a job at Y directly. It's very rare someone would go through the trouble of setting up presence for one potential hire.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I'm looking exclusively for employers that have presence in country Y. Made additional edits. Sorry, I just didn't realize that this was unclear too.

Comment: Take in account that if you relocate to Y, you will not be paid an X salary but an Y one. So I really don't understand why don't you just look for a job at Y directly. So to be clear: is your question: I want to work for a company based on X, that pays an x salary but I want to reallocate to a much cheaper y country?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I want to work for a company that has a location in Y. X and Y are almost the same economically. Salary is not a part of the question at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm only looking for positions that offer relocation (not necessary relocation assistance, just the ability to work in another country), but I'm not sure how to inform my potential employer that I NEED to relocate.

Clearly, this is a necessary requirement for you.

You should make it clear in your cover letter that you will need to relocate. And if you talk with a recruiter, you should make it clear.

You don't want to waste anyone's time (neither yours nor theirs) if this isn't possible with the potential employer.

> Is it appropriate to mention personal reasons, or the fact that if I accept the offer I will not be able to stay in my current country, or is it better to be as general as possible?

It makes sense to indicate "for family reasons". It will likely not be necessary to say more, unless they ask.

Comment: Yes, candidates should inform potential employers of any deal-breaker conditions ahead of time, not only to save time but to help us make sure the candidate is interviewing for the correct position. If a company offers remote-only positions, getting stuck interviewing for that team will ensure you don't get the job.

Answer (score 2):

> How to bring up relocation during a job interview?

In the interview, you should clearly tell the interviewers that you are not located in their country and you are currently in country X, but you will move to country Y. So, you will work for them remotely from country Y.

**This is a legitimate topic. So, you should be able to bring it up during the interviews to clear up any potential confusions.**

BTW, if you don't want to disclose the reason you move from country X to Y, then you don't have to or you can simply tell them it is due to a family reason.

---

In most cases, the employers probably don't care much about whether you work for them remotely from country X or Y except for some of  these situations:

1. Their government forbid them from doing business with anyone located
   in country X or Y due to economic sanction, embargo, or political reasons.
2. For tax purposes and saving costs, the companies may prefer hiring remote workers
   from certain countries.

Comment: Working remotely in a different country can be complicated because of different legal systems and taxation, and not all employers want to go through the trouble for a single employee